# JSON isn't loaded in selection field on dialog launch

Tags: json, xml, dialog, aem

This is my component's _cq_dialog 's .content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Store Tile" sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog" helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Carousel">
                    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs" type="nav" />
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <titletext jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Store Tile Properties" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                                <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns" />
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <storelist jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select" options="/apps/platform-do/components/general/store-tile/store.json" fieldLabel="Store" name="./jcr:storeID" optionsRoot="mydata" optionsTextField="label" optionsValueField="id" allowBlank="false" defaultValue="1" xtype="selection" type="select" />
                                        </items>
                                    </column>
                                </items>
                            </titletext>
                        </items>
                    </content>
                </jcr:root>
```

The field gets shown successfully but, the url "/apps/platform-do/components/general/store-tile/store.json" isn't loading...It should return this data:

```
{"mydata":[
  {"id":"1","label":"one"},
  {"id":"2","label":"two"},
  {"id":"3","label":"three"},
  {"id":"4","label":"four"},
  {"id":"5","label":"five"},
  {"id":"6","label":"six"}
]}
```

But the field stays empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing the desired JSON back if you hit <host>:<port>/apps/platform-do/components/general/store-tile/store.json in your browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `xtype selection` is not able to understand the JSON that your are feeding ("/apps/platform-do/components/general/store-tile/store.json") .

As per the [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection) , the format of the JSON has to be like the following one with `text , value and/or qtip.`

```
[
    {
        value: "pink", // all types except "combobox"
        text: "Pink",
        qtip: "Real Pink" // "select" and "combobox"
    }
]
```

Try to convert your `store.json` in the following structure and see if that works.

```
[
  {
    "text":"one",
    "value":"1"
  },
  {
    "text":"two",
    "value":"2"
  }
]
```